# pandas dataframe map using lambda function with multiple input arguments | AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

**Given**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user_ip': ["u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5"],
                        'a':  [1, np.nan, 8, 2, 0], 
                        'b':  [2, 5, 1, np.nan, 0], 
                        'c':  [3, 0, np.nan, 0, 7],
                        'd':  [0, 2, 1, 2, 9],
                    },
                  )

 user_ip   a     b       c      d
0   u1    1.0   2.0     3.0     0
1   u2    NaN   5.0     0.0     2
2   u3    8.0   1.0     NaN     1
3   u4    2.0   NaN     0.0     2
4   u5    0.0   0.0     7.0     9
```

**Goal**:

I'd like to loop through each row to get a new column using my custom defined function with input arguments (including `DataFrame` and its column) as follows:

```
def fcn(df, col, x, y):
    return x*df[col] + y

df["new_col_apply"] = df.apply(lambda inp_df: fcn(inp_df, col="b", x=2, y=10), axis=1)
```

My solution works fine but `apply()` method seems quite slow for my original `dataframe` containing more than `900K` rows.

I am aware of `map()` but since `DataFrame` doesn’t have `map()` transformation and I specifically need to input my `DataFrame` and its column (`col`) as input to my function `fcn`, my following snippet:

```
df["new_col_map"] = df.map(lambda inp_df: fcn(inp_df, col="b", x=2, y=10), na_action="ignore")
```

ends up in `AttributeError` as bellow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-14-dfe11c4bff87> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df["new_col_map"] = df.map(lambda inp_df: fcn(inp_df, col="b", x=2, y=10), na_action="ignore")
      2 df

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5900         ):
   5901             return self[name]
-> 5902         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5903 
   5904     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Is there any better and faster alternative than `apply()` transformation to loop through large pandas `DataFrame` with custom defined functions with several arguments?

Cheers,

Comment: Why apply, isn't it just `df['new_col'] = fcn(df, 'b', 2, 10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try directly invoking the function:

```py
df["new_col"] = fcn(df, col="b", x=2, y=10)
```